# docker php Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]

Tags: php, docker

In docker I get error message

```
Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
```

on my `php.ini` that is in `usr/local/lib/` I have

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Montreal
```

Comment: Are you sure that php.ini file is being used? I'd run a `phpinfo()` dump and double-check where PHP is sourcing its config.

Comment: Why not setting the default time zone in Docker container instead of PHP function? `TZ=America/Montreal`?

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path : /usr/local/lib

Comment: @Adiii : how to do setting the default time zone in Docker container

Comment: `ENV TZ="America/Montreal"` what is your base image?

Comment: @Adiii : my image is `site_web_1`

Comment: can your please post your Dockerfile or the link to dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by modifying

```
date.timezone = America/Montreal
```

To

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

`America/Montreal` is not a supported timezone.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Montreal [is in the `America/Toronto` timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The full list of available Canadian timezones in PHP can be output using `timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'CA')` and consists of the following:

```
[
     "America/Atikokan",
     "America/Blanc-Sablon",
     "America/Cambridge_Bay",
     "America/Creston",
     "America/Dawson",
     "America/Dawson_Creek",
     "America/Edmonton",
     "America/Fort_Nelson",
     "America/Glace_Bay",
     "America/Goose_Bay",
     "America/Halifax",
     "America/Inuvik",
     "America/Iqaluit",
     "America/Moncton",
     "America/Nipigon",
     "America/Pangnirtung",
     "America/Rainy_River",
     "America/Rankin_Inlet",
     "America/Regina",
     "America/Resolute",
     "America/St_Johns",
     "America/Swift_Current",
     "America/Thunder_Bay",
     "America/Toronto",
     "America/Vancouver",
     "America/Whitehorse",
     "America/Winnipeg",
     "America/Yellowknife",
]
```